# delete lines matching pattern if it is repeated

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

Say I have a config file:

```
[main]
foo = bar
[option]
opt1 = opt2
opt3 = opt4
[extra]
[footer]
[tail]
print = true
[end]
```

I want to print the headers (`[text]`) only if there are options underneath. So the output should be:

```
[main]
foo = bar
[option]
opt1 = opt2
opt3 = opt4
[tail]
print = true
```

Comment: Why must it be sed, rather than awk or perl?

Comment: @EdGrimm - It doesn't really. I just wanted some simple one-liner. I've removed sed from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I'd write this in multiple lines for legibility, but since you asked for a one-liner:

```
perl -ne '$head = $_ and next if /^\[/; $head and print $head and undef $head; print'
```

Comment: I recall seeing awk that could do it in fewer characters, but I don't use awk due to the overhead from always splitting lines into words.  For most uses, that difference in time is not relevant, but I've spent too much of my career writing log parsing scripts that consume multi-gigabyte logs, so I haven't exercised my awk muscles.

Comment: Thanks - I can convert that to awk as `awk '/^\[/{head=$0; next}head{print head;head=""}1'`

Answer (score 1):

portable sed; must not gnu sed, let your file is conf

```
 sed -E 'N;/^\[.+\]\n\[.+\]$/!P;D' conf
```

if gnu sed set it to basic portable

```
sed --posix -E 'N;/^\[.+\]\n\[.+\]$/!P;D' conf
```

Comment: POSIX `sed` has no `-E` option, but ok, "_more_ portable".

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/^\[/ { head = $0; next } head != "" { print head; head = "" } { print }' file
[main]
foo = bar
[option]
opt1 = opt2
opt3 = opt4
[tail]
print = true
```

This `awk` program saves each header found into the variable `head` and immediately skips to the next line of input.

If the line is *not* a header line, and if the `head` variable contains something, the header is outputted. The current line is then outputted.

This is a more or less straight translation of [Ed Grimm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501765/116858) into `awk`.

---

A more or less direct translation into `sed`, where the hold space is used to keep the most recent header, would look like

```
/^\[/ {
    h;    # store header in hold space (overwriting)
    d;    # delete pattern space, start next cycle
}

x;                   # swap with hold space
/./ { p; s///g; };   # if non-empty, print and empty
x;                   # swap with hold space
```

Or, as a one-liner,

```
$ sed -e '/^\[/{ h;d; }' -e 'x; /./{ p;s///g; }' -e x file
[main]
foo = bar
[option]
opt1 = opt2
opt3 = opt4
[tail]
print = true
```

---

An alternative but shorter `sed` variation that relies on the fact that there's an empty section/header at the end of the file:

```
$ sed -n -e'/^\[/{ x;/\n/p;d; }' -e H file
[main]
foo = bar
[option]
opt1 = opt2
opt3 = opt4
[tail]
print = true
```

This stores the header and the other lines associated with it in the hold space.  When a new header is found, the hold space is swapped in and a check for a newline character is done on it.  If one is found, it is printed.  Other lines are simply appended to the hold space.

As `awk`, this would look like

```
awk '/^\[/ { if (sect ~ ORS) print sect; sect = $0; next } { sect = sect ORS $0 }' file
```

Comment: This looks familiar ... hmmm

Comment: @DarkHeart Yes, it's more or less what you wrote in a comment, but properly testing `head` for an empty value, and explicitly using `{ print }`.

Comment: @DarkHeart Now with added `sed`.